# C# custom configuration: "The entry '' has already been added."

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager

I made a small custom configuration setting and I keep getting the error "The entry '' has already been added." when I try to use my custom collection. My code looks like this.

The issue comes from my  tag.

I don't see what I am missing since I have the same thing implemented for  and this one works perfectly.

My .NET version is 4.0 if that helps.

The app config section in question:

```
<WorkersCollectionSection>
<WorkersList>
  <Worker name="Category" isEnabled="false"
        assemblyNamespace="xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.Models.Category"
        queueName="CategorQueue"
        saveToFolder="false">
    <HandlesList>
      <Handle name="xxxxxxx" isEnabled="true"/>
      <Handle name="yyyyyyy" isEnabled="true"/>
      <Handle name="zzzzzzzzzz" isEnabled="true"/>
    </HandlesList>
  </Worker>
 <WorkersList>
<WorkersCollectionSection>
```

The definition of the  property:

```
    [ConfigurationProperty("HandlesList")]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(WorkerCollection), AddItemName = "Handle")]
    public HandleCollection HandleCollection
    {
        get { return (HandleCollection) base["HandlesList"]; }
    }
```

The code for the  tag :` public class HandleCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection, IEnumerable
    {

```
    public HandleCollection()
    {
        HandleElement handle = (HandleElement)CreateNewElement();
        BaseAdd(handle);
    }

    public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
    {
        get { return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.AddRemoveClearMap; }
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new HandleElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((HandleElement)element).Name;
    }

    public HandleElement this[int index]
    {
        get { return (HandleElement)BaseGet(index); }
        set
        {
            if (BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    public new HandleElement this[string Name]
    {
        get { return (HandleElement)BaseGet(Name); }
    }

    public int IndexOf(HandleElement handle)
    {
        return BaseIndexOf(handle);
    }

    public void Add(HandleElement url)
    {
        BaseAdd(url);
    }

    protected override void BaseAdd(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        BaseAdd(element, false);
    }

    public void Remove(HandleElement handle)
    {
        if (BaseIndexOf(handle) >= 0)
            BaseRemove(handle);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        BaseRemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void Remove(string name)
    {
        BaseRemove(name);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        BaseClear();
    }

    IEnumerator<ConfigurationElement> IEnumerable<ConfigurationElement>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, this.Count)
                select this[i])
            .GetEnumerator();
    }

    protected override string ElementName
    {
        get { return "Handle"; }
    }

    public static explicit operator HandleCollection(Dictionary<string, string> v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static explicit operator HandleCollection(ConfigurationSection v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}`
```

Code for the handle elements inside the list:

```
 public class HandleElement: ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    [StringValidator(InvalidCharacters = "~!@#$%^&*()[]{}/;'\"|\\", MinLength = 0, MaxLength = 60)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return base["name"] as string; }
        set { base["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("isEnabled", IsRequired = true)]
    public bool IsEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)base["isEnabled"]; }
        set { base["isEnabled"] = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: In the `<HandlesList>` section of your config, the first element has two opening angle brackets: `<<Handle name="RabbitMQHandle" isEnabled="true"/>'

Comment: That's a tipo. My bad.

Comment: have you registered your custom config section in the app.config file before adding it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was that I did not put a check in the collection adding method to check if the element I am adding has a different key than the empty one. I changed my collection constructor to :

```
 public HandleCollection()
    {
        HandleElement handle = (HandleElement)CreateNewElement();
        if (handle.Name != "")
            BaseAdd(handle);
    }
```

Now it seems to work fine.